# Here maps Group class in Android SDK? "Layers" in Here

Tags: android, here-api

(I'm a noobie to Here Maps)

Re: Madis' answer in [How can I add layers to Here Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050523/how-can-i-add-layers-to-here-maps/34063819)

I can't find the Group class in the Here Android SDK?

Does it only exist in the JavaScript API?

If so how do I access/use  it w/in an Android Studio application?

Or is there some other way to implement Layers w/ in the Here Android SDK?

Am I missing something? Is there some kind of relationship/linkage between the Here JS api and the Here Android SDK? Can one access the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [MapContainer](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-objects-and-interaction.html#map-objects-and-interaction__class-map-container).

**Bonus:** you can also get [Marker Clustering](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/marker-clustering.html) if you desire.

---

Additional JavaDocs:

- [MapContainer](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapcontainer.html)
- [Maker Clustering](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-cluster-intro.html)

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised it's not called "Group" ...?
Seems to indicate some kinda divergence from the older, more fundamental JavaScript api....?

Comment: This is a good point, it would be nice to have similar concepts aligned with the same name across APIs.

Comment: To be fair, it used to be called map.Container in older versions of the JS API (https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/maps_js_pub/2.5.4/Maps%20API%20for%20JavaScript%20Public%20v2.5.4%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf page 384). They changed the name to Group only in V3 of the JS API.